# How to send an android system intent?

Tags: java, android, galaxy

Because of the bug described [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1134741) i want to write a little android app to fix the problem in an indirect approach.

I want to write a program that disconnect and reconnect the charger programmatically.

I am new to java and to android applications ( although i know very well c,c++,C#).

from here i am not sure i am on the right way, so i will be happy to hear another solution.
the one i came up with is to send an intent called BATTERY_CHANGED as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).

i quote: "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system."

I want to send it so the battery state of charging will change (of course, when battery is full)
i couldn't "touch" this method, the IDE(eclipse,with sdk, with ADT plugin, on win 7 x64) could not recognize the android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED as an existing value.
another two things i thought might be useful:
developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED

Answer (score 0):

Speaking generally about rechargeable batteries, especially Lithium containing ones, the charging is NOT controlled by software the user (or developer) can tamper with. This would be way too dangerous as overloading Lithium batteries will cause them to fail catastrophically. MAYBE you could manage to make the charging process stop, but I doubt that.

Comment: I think the problem is that the charger turns off and he wants to turn it back on.

Comment: It's too risky to do so, so the hardware design will not allow that.

Comment: im not after turning the charger on and off.I want to make the SGS think the the charger was disconnected, and then connected again. i let it choose whether to charge or not. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sending `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` will not affect the charging, even if you could broadcast it yourself, which only the firmware can do.

Comment: so what will affect the charging(theoretically , even if i can't touch it)?

Comment: @Yoav R.: Nothing at the SDK level will affect charging.